# Tumblr blog: External links redirects failing

Tags: html, redirect, themes, tumblr

[ [Tumblr][1](http://forsakenoathkeeper.tumblr.com) ]
[ [Example Post][2](http://forsakenoathkeeper.tumblr.com/post/139499054697/soras-radio) ]

I have a bizarre issue with my tumblr and have spoken with various HTML supporters on tumblr, and was reccomended this website because they have no idea what's causing this issue. Please refer to example post. Any links on my tumblr theme that direct off tumblr fail. The example post are links to youtube, for example. When clicked, it redirects, but remains on my theme, to a "not found" error. The URL shows it is trying to redirect and puts all sorts of % and periods randomly throughout the URL.

The only solution thus far offered is to put "http:\" in front of each link. I double checked, and they all have this protocol in front. I imagine something in my theme is causing this. If anyone knows what adjustments I need to make to stop this issue, I would be very grateful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: edit your question and add the code that you are having issues with